# Scrum Developer .. or am I?

Tags: project-management, agile, scrum

I work in a SCRUM team and we had a session of pokering just minutes ago.
I had (still have) an idea of 'how should I poker' but my team had another idea of it. I come today in front of you to ask if I should change the way I see pokering or is the environment (team) not 'SCRUM-enaugh'...

We had this story .. I pokered 50 storypoints (the numbers are not important, the idea is), 2 colleagues pokered 10, the rest of the team pokered an average of 25. We talked over this a bit and we decided to repoker.

As my experience has not improved during the talks, nor the requirements changed, I decided to  still poker 50 on it while the rest of the team 'agreed' on a 25 storyPoints estimation.

```
25 remained.
```

My argument: after the talks, I consider my knowledge on the story is the same, the requirements are the same thus my estimation is the same.

Team argument: after the talks, we saw that there are 2 guys that know exactly what the story is about and they estimated 25 so we are going to poker all 25 because 'there would be a 25 sp effort of the team'

***Should I change the way I see pokering or is the environment (team) not 'SCRUM-enaugh'... ??***

Thank you guys.

Comment: This is really more appropriate on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The situation looks good enough to me. When people after discussion still do not converge toward same estimation, it is a common practice to take the mean (in your case about 25).

It is also common that different people in a team have different "bias": some people tend to over-estimate all stories, other tends to lower-estimate. That's why the mean is a good estimation.

Anyway, after some iterations, you and the team will have more knowledge about the difficulty of this kind of story. The estimation should become easier as all team members would be able to refer to a past experience instead of a best-guess of a complexity.

Comment: Ok but this does not answer my question. Shall I change my estimation just because other team member says: ok I know what this is about, I estimate 10 SP. In other words: should I estimate on what impact (in SP) would have the story on the team, or what impact would have on myself ?

Comment: You should estimate on the impact it would have on the team. I expect the story is implemented by the team, so everybody are interested by the complexity for the team to implement it, not just you alone. And yes, when several persons declares they know what has to be done, and seem confident, you can change your estimation and join their. You would then later analyse where was the misinterpretation: maybe lack of information on your side or maybe too much confidence on their side. You (the team) could then make better next time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change your estimation, if you can justify. And if you could justify, then the team is not 'SCRUM-enough'. And then the team needs to go through it's estimation procedure and check out for improvements :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is what our teams call "conflict resolution".  Every time we put together a team on a project, part of our team charter is to get everybody to agree to a **conflict resolution model**.   We use this to ensure that in the case where we do not have 100% consensus, we have a model that everyone has agreed to to resolve the difference.

In your case, your model starts by having a discussion and re-estimation to attempt to get folks onto the same number.  When that fails, most of your team seemed to believe that taking the mean/average/most voted as the estimation was correct.  By your question, I tend to think you had not agreed with that approach.

On some of our teams, we have used a "competition" model, like rock-paper-scissors, to determine a victor.  Sometimes it's always "highest wins" so that if the person who grabs the story is the person who needs more time they have the points to do it.  Sometimes it's "majority rules", as seems to be the case on your team.

I would suggest to your scrum master or product owner to have the team agree on a single model that everybody agrees to so that everybody knows what they are getting into.  Something like the following.

**Model:**

1. **Step One:** Discuss for 2 minutes and re-estimate.
2. **Step Two:** If still deadlocked, choose majority.
3. **Step Three:** If no clear majority, choose higher value.

Obviously, this probably isn't the model you'll use, but it's an example of how you can go about getting your team to agree to something that always has an outcome and still allows the basic principle of talking it out first.  The most important thing is that everybody knows what the model is, and everybody agrees to it.

Comment: Your ideas are very interesting and I see no reason this wouldn't  work. Thank you for your answer.